# Why are the Alderaan destruction stories in the Eclipse short story (Canon), and Episode 4 different?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

In the Eclipse short story, it says that Bail and his wife saw the explosion coming towards them, but in Episode 4, the planet immediately explodes. Is there a reason for this discrepancy, or was it just a mistake in the story? If anyone has any answers, I would greatly appreciate them.

Comment: Out of universe answer: Disney is incapable of maintaining a coherent canon.

Comment: 'From a Certain Point of View' is a weird quantum state of simultaneously both canon and non-canon.  Stories can have unreliable narrators, some extra drama added in, or just plain wrong.  Due to the fact that most of the people involved are going "Maybe it is, maybe it isn't", I wouldn't treat eclipse as canon.

Comment: Note that the narrator is a dead character. Maybe her ghost saw it :-)

Comment: In this case, I would point out other movie canon instances that contradict ANH on the Death Star's effects. For instance, Scarif and Jedha in Rogue One. Both of those have an expanding effect radius (I know that Jedha didn't take a full blast, is was only partially powered, but these are just examples that show that this might have to do with @Null's idea that Disney can't maintain coherent canon). Although, this short story might not be evidence to that since Disney neither wrote nor published it.

Comment: @JeremyNielsen - It was published, as all things Star Wars are now published, with the explicit permission of the Lucasfilm Story Group.

Comment: @Valorum, whether or not Lucasfilm approved it, it was published well before Disney took over. My main point in saying that they didn't publish it was to show that it is not really proof of Disney's inability to maintain coherent/consistent canon (although I definitely agree that they need help in that department, and not just for Star Wars)

Answer (score 2):

The very short answer is that the stories in the book are canon in precisely the same way as the film novelisations, graphic novels, etc. Where they *agree* with the most recent version of the films, they're canon. Where they *disagree*, they're not.

Matt Martin of the Lucasfilm Story Group relates this to Greedo/Han shooting first, but the same principle would clearly apply across the other stories too.

> **Q.** *Okay. Only fate will decide. Thanks, Matt. But before leaving, I had just one more question: Which Episode IV version is the canon one? The original or the Special Edition? In From a Certain Point of View, Han shoots Greedo first, contradicting the latter...*
>
> **MM:** ***FACPOV has a lot of contradictions, that’s sort of the nature of that
> project. But yeah, the latest film release is most accurate**.*
>
> <sub><sup>[via Twitter - Matt Martin - Lucasfilm Story Group](https://web.archive.org/web/20190419223021/https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1033837757695545344)</sup></sub>